# Unusual function declaration in C

Tags: c, function, gcc

I am reading the source code of `GCC 3.1` recently, and I have found some weird function declarations.

For example:

```
struct c_fileinfo *
get_fileinfo (name)
     const char *name;
{
  splay_tree_node n;
  struct c_fileinfo *fi;

  n = splay_tree_lookup (file_info_tree, (splay_tree_key) name);
  if (n)
    return (struct c_fileinfo *) n->value;

  fi = (struct c_fileinfo *) xmalloc (sizeof (struct c_fileinfo));
  fi->time = 0;
  fi->interface_only = 0;
  fi->interface_unknown = 1;
  splay_tree_insert (file_info_tree, (splay_tree_key) name,
             (splay_tree_value) fi);
  return fi;
}
```

I guess the declaration is equivalent to

`struct c_fileinfo *get_fileinfo (const char* name)`

right?

**And why does the code need to be written this way?**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "And why does the code need to be written this way?" -  **You should never write a function definition like that! It is a legacy and obsolecent, i.e. it is to be removed from the standard.** Just forget this ever existed! Use modern C and a good textbook which covers at least C99, better standard C, i.e. C11 to learn the language.

Comment: OK, I am just being curious, thank you for your explanation.@Olaf